# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll;

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have problem, Additional information:

> The parameterized query '(@id nvarchar(4000),@MaKhachHang nvarchar(4),@MaHang nvarchar(40' expects the parameter '@id', which was not supplied.

```
using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(sqlCnt))
{
    for (int i = 1; i < metroGrid2.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Yeucaukhachang(id,MaKhachHang,MaHang,TenHang,DonViTinh,Dongia,SoLuong,Duyet) 
                values(@id,@MaKhachHang,@MaHang,@TenHang,@DonViTinh,@Dongia,@SoLuong,@Duyet)", sqlCon);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaKhachHang", makh.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaHang", metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TenHang", metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SoLuong", metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DonViTinh", metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dongia", metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Duyet", 'N');
        sqlCon.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlCon.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Thêm thành công, chuyển qua xác nhận yêu cầu");
   }              
}
```

Comment: use the debugger to step through the code and evaluate the necessary values.. do not just `Code & Go` as we say in programming..

Answer (score 2):

The error message is a little misleading.  The problem is most likely that the value you're providing for `@id` is `null` which is not converted to `DBNull.value`.  Try this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", (object) metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
```

This will use the null coalescing operator `??` to detect when your value is null and replace it with `DBNull.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely handing `null`. You can coalesce the value passed for `@id` as`metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value??DBNull.Value`, which will prepare a value for `@id` regardless of whether the source data is `null`.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: sr, i'm testing `metroGrid2` value

Comment: Your suggested code throws a compiler error?  Did you try it?